# Enforcing Case Insensitive uniqueness on fields at a given nesting level using angularjs

Tags: forms, validation, angularjs, unique

```
 <FORM>
 <DIV class="outer-class">
      <INPUT class="toValidate" type = "text"/>
      <INPUT class="somethingElse" type= "text"/>
      <INPUT class="toValidate" type ="text"/>
 </DIV>
 <DIV class="outer-class">
      <INPUT class="toValidate" type = "text"/>
      <INPUT class="somethingElse" type= "text"/>
      <INPUT class="toValidate" type ="text"/>
 </DIV>
 <INPUT type="submit"/>
 </FORM>
```

My question is: How do I ensure that for the form to be valid, the nested toValidates have a unique value but only within the same outer div?
I am guessing this logic should go in an OuterClassDirective, but I can't seem to figure out what the logic should look like?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You mean a unique value typed in the text fields?

Comment: Yeah, either typer or populated from the server on initial page load

Comment: In general, it's a bad idea to populate the fields at the server. It's better to send JSON from the server to the client and let Angular handle that.

Comment: @blesh, sorry that's what I meant when I said "populated from the server" I should have been clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this. Your outerClassDirective should have a controller, which will store used values in an array. It will transclude the input fields in its body. Your toValidate directive  requires outerClassDirective and adds the model value to the array, making it invalid if exists.

Here is a try (untested):

```
app.directive('outerClass', function() {
   var values = [];
   var valid = true;
   return {
      template: '<div ng-transclude></div>',
      transclude: true,
      replace: true,
      require: 'ngModel',
      controller: function() {
         this.addValue: function(value) {
            valid = values.indexOf(value) > -1;
            values.push(value);
         };
      },
      link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
         ctrl.$setValidity('toValidate', valid)
      }
   };
});

app.directive('toValidate', function() {
   return {
        require: '^outerClass',
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
           ctrl.addValue(attrs.value);
        } 
      }
   };
});
```

Comment: I may have accepted prematurely - I've fixed the syntax errors, and seem to now get the following:

Error: No controller: ngModel

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Your outerClass tag needs a ng-model attribute.

Comment: Ahh yes. Thanks. Any suggestions for what would make a good ng-model value? I've currently set it to ng-model="$index" (its nested in an ng-repeat), as (I don't think?) I need to tie the divs model to anything?

Comment: You don't understand the setup. If one of the input tags detects that its value already exists, it will flag the model on the parent tag (outerClass) as invalid. So you just need a new model object (e.g. groupOfFields), which you can test on form submit (e.g if(groupOfFields.$invalid) ...).

Answer (score 1):

The 'tabs' and 'pane' directives on the Angular home page solve a similar issue -- the child 'pane' directives need to communicate with the parent 'tabs' directive.

Define a controller on the outerclass directive, and then define a method on the controller (use `this` not $scope).  Then `require: '^outerclass'` in the toValidate directive.  In the toValidate link function, you can $watch for value changes and call the method on the outerclass controller to pass the value up.  Do the validation in the outerclass directive.

See also ['this' vs $scope in AngularJS controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11605917/this-vs-scope-in-angularjs-controllers/14168699#14168699).